# what does "ride-along" mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

What does it mean ?

Hank took me on a `ride-along` and showed me just how much money even a small meth operation could make.

It was in Breaking Bad

Comment: [Easily found in a dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ride-along). And knowing Hank is a policeman you needn't go very far to get your explanation.

Comment: thnx Laure, I got it !!! rep 1+

Answer (score 1):

A ride-along is an arrangement for a civilian to spend a shift in the passenger seat of a police car, observing the work day of a police officer, firefighter, or paramedic.
Ride-alongs are offered by many police departments around the world. There is a minimum age to participate in a ride-along. Depending on the department, it is often somewhere between the ages of 14 and 18. When participation of those under 18 is permitted, consent from a parent or legal guardian may be required. Those with criminal records or problems on previous ride-alongs may also be barred from participation. The most common form of ride-alongs are Law Enforcement Explorers, or Auxiliary or Volunteer Police officers.
People go on ride-alongs for various reasons. These include interest in a future career in law enforcement, personal interest in law enforcement without such a career, journalists wishing to write reports, and those interested in community relations. Regardless of the reason, all citizens who meet the department's eligibility requirements are generally welcome on a ride-along.
The television show "COPS" is made with a variety of police ride-alongs put into a half hour segment.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ride_along

Comment: First thing when I got when I googled the phrase!